# How can i insert more than 150 Account records in Salesforce without a Limit exception?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am running the statement in the Debug->Open Execute Anonymous Window option. I am trying to insert more than 150 Account records

```
  List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
  for(Integer i = 0; i < 200; i++)
  {
     Account account = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
     accounts.add(account);
  }
  insert accounts;  // insert list - counts as 1 DML statement.
```

But i get the error:

```
  System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 151
```

Is there a way i can do this ?

Comment: This code is fine, you have to have a Trigger on account that is performing other dmls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, it's bulkified OK.

You need to examine the debug log carefully. You probably have a trigger on Account object (before insert, after insert etc) And something in there is written in suboptimal way. Creating data in a loop. A Task maybe? Updating something? The exact stack trace of where the limit was breached should help to nail it down.

If you don't have a trigger there's still way to run apex code for example from flow/process builder - but again, viewing the debug & stacktrace will help to nail it down.

Comment: eyescream  - There was a trigger on Account. that was the issue